# How to apply custom sound effect like equalizer in macOS?

Tags: macos, audio, system-settings

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2014 - 15-inch model. The speaker is making weird noise instead of proper bass. Doing a few trials I found out a suitable custom equalizer setting in a media player. When I am using this player and toggle this setting, the sound quality is a little bit better.

**I was wondering if there is a way in which I can use this setting to the entire OS!
so every sound including notification rings, alarms etc will have this effect that minimizes the creepy sound for me?
If yes, how?**

Comment: Is this weird noise by any chance a kind of buzzing/vibrating noise? If so the chances are the speaker cones are damaged & the only long-term fix is to replace them; they will continue to get worse.

Comment: Yes, but right now I can't replace due to Lockdown in my area. So I am looking for a temporary solution.

Comment: I don't know of any free solution, so let's see if someone else can come up with one in an answer, but the go-to paid app for anything like this is [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/)

Comment: Try this: https://eqmac.app/